# PyPolars, conditional join on two columns

Tags: python, dataframe, left-join, python-polars

How should one join two `pl.LazyFrame` using two columns from each `pl.LazyFrame` based on content in the columns of the left `pl.LazyFrame` ?

```py
import polars as pl

lf1 = pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "col_1": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "col_2": ["d", None, None],
        "col_3": [None, "e", None],
    },
    schema={
        "col_1": pl.Utf8,
        "col_2": pl.Utf8,
        "col_3": pl.Utf8,
    },
)

lf2 = pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "col_a": ["d", "xyz"],
        "col_b": ["xyz", "e"],
        "col_c": ["relevant_info_1", "relevant_info_2"],
    },
    schema={
        "col_a": pl.Utf8,
        "col_b": pl.Utf8,
        "col_c": pl.Utf8,
    },
)
```

Pseudo-code of desired join :

```
lf1.join(lf2,
  when(col("col_2").isnotnull().then(left_on="col_2", right_on="col_a")
  when(col("col_3").isnotnull().then(left_on="col_3", right_on="col_b")
  otherwise(do_nothing)
)
```

Expected result :

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_c
a     | d     | None  | relevant_info_1
b     | None  | e     | relevant_info_2
c     | None  | None  | None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to first make the two joins **inner** separately.
Then we can filter `LF1` to select only rows with `col_2` and `col_3` being both `None`. Finally, we can concatenate the three `pl.LazyFrame` to obtain final result.

That solution uses only 2 joins instead of 3 for the solution provided by @robertdj. Thus might explain the faster execution of following `foo1()`.

```py
import polars as pl

LF1 = pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "col_1": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "col_2": ["d", None, None],
        "col_3": [None, "e", None],
    },
    schema={
        "col_1": pl.Utf8,
        "col_2": pl.Utf8,
        "col_3": pl.Utf8,
    },
)

LF2 = pl.LazyFrame(
    data={
        "col_a": ["d", "xyz"],
        "col_b": ["xyz", "e"],
        "col_c": ["relevant_info_1", "relevant_info_2"],
    },
    schema={
        "col_a": pl.Utf8,
        "col_b": pl.Utf8,
        "col_c": pl.Utf8,
    },
)


def foo1() -> pl.DataFrame:
    lf_joined_on_col_2 = (
        LF1.join(other=LF2, left_on=["col_2"], right_on=["col_a"])
        .with_columns(pl.lit(None).cast(pl.Utf8).alias("col_a"))
        .select(["col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_c"])
    )
    lf_joined_on_col_3 = (
        LF1.join(other=LF2, left_on=["col_3"], right_on=["col_b"])
        .with_columns(pl.lit(None).cast(pl.Utf8).alias("col_b"))
        .select(["col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_c"])
    )

    lf_rows_with_null_on_col_2_and_col_3 = LF1.filter(
        pl.col("col_2").is_null() & pl.col("col_3").is_null()
    ).with_columns(pl.lit(None).cast(pl.Utf8).alias("col_c"))

    return pl.concat(
        [lf_joined_on_col_2, lf_joined_on_col_3, lf_rows_with_null_on_col_2_and_col_3]
    ).collect()


def foo2() -> pl.DataFrame:
    lf_joined_on_col_2 = LF1.join(
        other=LF2, left_on=["col_2"], right_on=["col_a"], how="left"
    )
    lf_joined_on_col_3 = LF1.join(
        other=LF2, left_on=["col_3"], right_on=["col_b"], how="left"
    )

    return (
        lf_joined_on_col_2.join(
            lf_joined_on_col_3.select(["col_1", "col_c"]), on=["col_1"]
        )
        .with_columns(pl.coalesce(["col_c", "col_c_right"]).alias("col_c"))
        .select(["col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_c"])
    ).collect()
```

Solution `foo2()` provided by @robertdj is slightly slower than my solution `foo1()` :

```
> python -m timeit -n 1000 -s "import test1" "test1.foo1()"
1000 loops, best of 5: 4.76 msec per loop
> python -m timeit -n 1000 -s "import test1" "test1.foo2()"
1000 loops, best of 5: 6.57 msec per loop
```

Comment: You should probably be using `.collect()` in the comparisons as the queries may have different runtimes.

Comment: @jqurious wow you totally right ! Turned out my `foo1` is faster (6.5msec vs 4.7msec), I will update my answer, many thanks.

Comment: Both methods also produce different results depending on the inputs e.g. if you concat both dataframes `LF1 = pl.concat([LF1] * 2); LF2 = pl.concat([LF2] * 2)` - `foo1` gives 10 rows, `foo2` gives 20 rows - so it's not clear what the "correct" output should be here.

Comment: `foo1` gives the expected result, `foo2` will require an extra `.unique()` call since it's just a duplication.

Comment: Both functions create duplicates on that case. But results are identical if you run `.unique()` on the final `pl.DataFrame` for both functions.

Comment: Understood - thanks. Just out of interest, trying it on larger examples (500k rows) - `foo1` wins by quite a margin for me.

Comment: With the revelation that foo1 is actually faster I undeleted my answer which is similar to `foo1` but with a couple differences that *might* make it faster but should certainly obviate the need for `unique`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way. First we make the two joins separately:

```py
join1 = lf1.join(lf2, left_on=["col_2"], right_on=["col_a"], how="left").collect()
join2 = lf1.join(lf2, left_on=["col_3"], right_on=["col_b"], how="left").collect()
```

Then `join1` and `join2` can be joined and the desired `col_c` is made by coalescing the `col_c`s from `join1` and `join2`.
I only keep the final columns you ask for, but I may be instructive to remove the `select` statement.

```py
(
    join1
    .join(
        join2.select(['col_1', 'col_c'])
        , on=["col_1"]
    )
    .with_columns(pl.coalesce(['col_c', 'col_c_right']).alias('col_c'))
    .select(['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3', 'col_c'])
)
```

Comment: You can remove the `.collect()` calls from `join1/join2` and just have a single `.collect()` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do conditional joins. You just have to do the joins you want and then put them together.

```
pl.concat([
    lf1.filter(pl.col('col_2').is_not_null())
        .join(lf2.select('col_a', 'col_c'), 
              left_on='col_2', right_on='col_a', how='left'),
    lf1.filter(pl.col('col_3').is_not_null())
        .join(lf2.select('col_b', 'col_c'), 
              left_on='col_3', right_on='col_b', how='left'),
    lf1.filter((pl.col('col_2').is_null()) & (pl.col('col_3').is_null()))
        .with_columns(col_c=pl.lit(None, pl.Utf8()))
    ], how='diagonal').collect()
```

This is similar to your own `foo1` but has a some tweaks such as filtering each step and making the joins `left` instead of the default `inner`. With those tweaks you don't need a `unique` at the end since each item in the concat is already exclusive.

The good thing about this approach is that the joins will be performed in parallel (only for LazyFrames) since the default of [`concat`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html#polars.concat) is to run them in parallel. I suspect if you did this with DataFrames instead of LazyFrames that it wouldn't be faster.